# JSON.stringify returning []

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why would `JSON.stringify()` return:

```
[]
```

The same happens with jQuery: `$.JSON.encode()`

What could cause this? I am passing in a simple array of objects, where each object has string properties. I have looped through and alerted each objects properties and all looks fine, but for some reason both the encode methods are returning `[]`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify([]) === "[]"`. Your array of objects is probably empty.

Comment: Not necessary empty, but non-enumerable elements.

Comment: I've solved this, it's the string array keys. Can't post my own answer for another 8 hours.

Comment: BTW, arrays do not have string keys. Ever. By definition. It sounds like you mangled an array by pretending that it's an object (i.e. what @evilpie said); don't do this.

Comment: "BTW, arrays do not have string keys." Arrays are just regular objects, but i agree you should avoid abusing them.

Comment: @Chris It means you had an empty JSON Object, how did you fill the JSON Object, is it: jsonObj.push(id:"id",optionValue:"value")?

Answer (score 85):

IN your array declaration

```
var count_review= new Array()
```

instead of this use

```
var count_review={};
```

It Works!

Comment: Those two lines aren't the same. The first is an array, the second an object. Array: `var count_review = [];`...

Comment: If you are using JavaScript objects as associative arrays (aka, using string keys instead of int keys), this answer is correct.

Comment: Using `var my_array = []` doesn't work for me in this case (Android Cordova). Make sure to use `var my_array = {}` even if passing an array afterwards. Doing so solved the problem.

Comment: I had this happen when concatenating objects in a Promise.reduce.  Needed to set the intial value to {}, and that fixed it.

Comment: That worked. I had initialized my ""array"" with somearray = [] , then filled it with objects (key-value pairs) and then tried to retrieve with stringify. It returned me a empty array everytime. Initializing it the proper way with {} (as a object) solved the problem. It seems I lack some basic knoweledge on diferences between Arrays and Objects.

Answer (score 36):

If your array uses a `string` key value, instead of an `int`, stringify ignores that value.

```
var array = [];
array['name'] = 'johan';
array['age'] = 20;
alert(JSON.stringify(array))// return []
```

But if array uses an "int" as a key, then `stringify` will return it.

```
var array = [];
array[0] = 'johan';
array[1] = 20;
alert(JSON.stringify(array))// return["johan",20]
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you so much!

Comment: what if I want to have the keys as string?!

Comment: you can use object type instead of array : `var obj = { name: "John", age: 20, city: "New York" }; alert(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Answer (score 16):

While the answers above are true, to fully understand it definitely needs more context.

JSON is an universal format (in the sense of supporting multiple, hopefully all programming languages) that is not entirely a 1-to-1 mapping of JavaScript objects.

So the root reason for why this happens is that in JSON (as specified by [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)) there are no associative arrays in the JavaScript's `Array` sense -- i.e. arrays whose keys are strings. As reading RFC specs can be rather time-consuming, it can be most easily seen on top of the [JSON.org](http://json.org) website where it says (*some of emphasis below is mine*):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an *object*, *record*, *struct*, *dictionary*, *hash table*, *keyed list*, or ***associative array***.
> - An *ordered list* of values. In most languages, this is realized as an ***array***, *vector*, *list*, or *sequence*.
>
> These are universal data structures. Virtually all modern programming languages support them in one form or another. It makes sense that a data format that is interchangeable with programming languages also be based on these structures.
>
> In JSON, they take on these forms:
>
> An *object* is an ***unordered*** set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace). Each name is followed by `:` (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` (comma).
>
> [image: JSON Object definition graph]
>
> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
>
> [image: JSON Array definition graph]

The `JSON.stringify` function handles this in such way that assuming that array is intended to be an array, and all keyed entries are annotative, so much like elements that are function objects, they are just thrown out of the JSON representation it returns. Unfortunately this behaviour is not documented in a well defined and easily understandable way in the unofficial JavaScript reference that is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) as of today (2017-09-04) so here is some low-hanging fruit if you want to help the ol' Mozilla.

Comment: This was for my the right answer: To use only numerical index on json.

Comment: Amazing answer, this is why I come to stack overflow even when there is chatGPT: to learn things I didn’t intend to, when finding any solution for an answer.

Answer (score 15):

I came accros same problem because my json array key-value was string-string. It is not possible to change the structure. So i solve my problem by converting my json array to
json object and it solves my problem completely. Json object successfully stringified.

To Change array to object :

```
var *your_object* = Object.assign({}, *your_array*);
```

Comment: I had an array which could not be stringfied [OCX938: "fgdgdfgfdgfdgdf"]. This solves the problem

Comment: I've had an object {5666440609949: true, 5638880067741: true} and this approach solved the issue for me