# Merging two multidimensional arrays based on matching keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

So currently I am generating records that should be grouped together to form the following JSON:

```
{
  "Monday": [{
      "Index": "1",
      "To": "200",
      "From": "1200"
    },
    {
      "Index": "2",
      "To": "1300",
      "From": "1400"
    }
  ],
  "Tuesday": [{
      "Index": "1",
      "To": "100",
      "From": "200"
    },
    {
      "Index": "2",
      "To": "1000",
      "From": "1200"
    },
    {
      "Index": "3",
      "To": "1300",
      "From": "1500"
    }
  ]
}
```

But currently, the output looks more like this:

[image]

As you can see, two records that share the same "Index" value are being created- this is mainly because I have yet to figure out how to do a `where index = <index> insert` to handle finding records with matching indexes and adding the properties to it.

Currently, the code looks like this-

```
var controlsJson;
//Assume two loops are running through different sets of values for "type". setting them to "To" and "From" pragmatically.
//Array building
if (controlsJson == null) {
  controlsJson = [];
}
if (controlsJson[date] == null) {
  controlsJson[date] = [];
}
var pusher = [];
pusher["Index"] = index;
pusher[type] = time;
controlsJson[date].push(pusher);
```

Is there any other ways I can improve this aside from solving the issue with matching index keys?

Comment: Post your desired output!

Comment: ^^ and the input objects in test form!

Comment: The desired output is the first JSON I posted. 

The current output is the one in the picture.

Comment: Look to the right of your question. There's a number of questions linked in the Related section. At least one of those will likely answer your question.

Comment: None of them cover using properties dynamically as I do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **cchamberlain** pointed out, I was approaching indexes in a much more complicated manner than was really necessary.

I modified my code to the following and using an immutable approach (I think that's what it is called), records can be added pragmatically just by using an index!

```
//Array building
if (controlsJson == null) {
    controlsJson = [];
}
if (controlsJson[date] == null) {
    controlsJson[date] = [];
}

if (controlsJson[date][index] == null) {
    controlsJson[date][index] = [];
}

controlsJson[date][index][type] = time;
}
```

Also note that if you wish to use JSON.Stringify, you will need to change the  = [] into = {}

Again- if you fell I can further improve this code, let me know.

Comment: Just to fix some nomenclature, this is actually not an immutable approach but it looks fine if you aren't aiming for immutability. This is not immutable because you are directly mutating your object at the `[date][index][type]` path. This strategy definitely looks easier to work with than the original approach you were attempting.

Comment: not sure I follow, arrays are valid JSON structures so `JSON.stringify` should handle both `[]` (arrays) and `{}` (objects).

Comment: I didn't either, but apparently it matters. I was getting an empty array with `[]` but got a proper response when I used `{}` 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259728/json-stringify-returning

Comment: Ahh, if you declare the structure as an array and then assign string properties to it, they won't show up in the results because arrays can also work like hash tables so that's probably what happened to you.

Comment: I think thats it- I tried viewing it as a string via `console.log` and then setting the `.val()` of a hidden field, which both would cause it.

Thank you for all the help cchamberlain!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot easier to traverse if you instead represent your data in the following format:

```js
let state = {
  Monday: {
    1: {
      To: 200,
      From: 1200
    },
    2: {
      To: 1300,
      From: 1400
    }
  },
  Tuesday: {
    1: {
      To: 100,
      From: 200
    },
    2: {
      To: 1000,
      From: 1200
    },
    3: {
      To: 1300,
      From: 1500
    }
  }
}

state = { ...state, Tuesday: { ...state.Tuesday, 2: { To: 1500, From: 1400 } } }

console.log(state)
```

If you do not care about immutability, the following would also work:

```js
let state = {
  Monday: {
    1: {
      To: 200,
      From: 1200
    },
    2: {
      To: 1300,
      From: 1400
    }
  },
  Tuesday: {
    1: {
      To: 100,
      From: 200
    },
    2: {
      To: 1000,
      From: 1200
    },
    3: {
      To: 1300,
      From: 1500
    }
  }
}

state["Tuesday"][2] = { To: 1500, From: 1400 };

console.log(state)
```

Comment: Haha, this is actually how I originally intended to represent it, but I felt like it would have been problematic if I ended up having non standard indexes. 
Would it?

Comment: From the standpoint of merging data it's much easier to work with indexed objects like the above than handling with arrays. If you did it with an array, I would not use indexes at all (reference via ordinals instead). Another thing to consider is whether you should be adhering to immutable state updates. The example above will create a brand new object and merge your previous state to it, vs. mutating the existing state.

Comment: @Bitz I added an example thats simpler, if you do not care to work in an immutable way.

Comment: @Bitz to answer your comment, this would work for any index (string, number, etc.), it stores them as a hashtable essentially running a `toString()` on the index and using that key to store against.

Comment: I think you are right, I will adopt this approach as it seems to simplify adding data significantly. Thank you. I will accept this as an answer and provide source code to implement this approach.

Comment: I added my answer, let me know if you see any way I can improve it further. It now provides output as you suggested!

Comment: @bitz If you are working heavily with state mutation on deeply nested structures, you may have a look at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/. It's data structures allow you to walk down paths of your data, in this case an update could look like `state = state.setIn([ 'Tuesday', 2, 'To' ], 2000);`.

Answer (score 0):

If for each day the index will start with 0, this little snippet should do the trick:

```
// your object that you start with
var days = {
    'Monday': [
        {Index: 0, Start: 330},
        {Index: 0, End: 1330},
        {Index: 1, Start: 330},
        {Index: 1, End: 1330},
        {Index: 2, Start: 330},
        {Index: 2, End: 1330},
    ],
    'Tuesday': [
        {Index: 0, Start: 330},
        {Index: 0, End: 1330},
        {Index: 1, Start: 330},
        {Index: 1, End: 1330},
        {Index: 2, Start: 330},
        {Index: 2, End: 1330},
        {Index: 3, Start: 330},
        {Index: 3, End: 1330},
    ],
};

// create an array of indexes. For each index, filter days by that Index,
// then pass those to Object.assign to merge the 2 items together.
var i, dayMaxIndex;
for (i in days) {
    if (days.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        dayMaxIndex = Math.max.apply(null, days[i].map(function(d) { return d.Index; }));
        days[i] = Array.from({length: dayMaxIndex+1}, (v, i) => i).map(function(d) {
            return Object.assign.apply(null, days[i].filter(function(day) {
                return day.Index == d;
            }));
        });
    }
}
console.log(days);
```

You can ready more about Object.assign [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

I found this piece was a little confusing to work with:

```
Array.from({length: dayMaxIndex+1}, (v, i) => i)
```

it generates an array of sequential numbers, starting with 0 and ends at dayMaxIndex. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from) where I found this example.