# How to send an array of data to the Backend (php) through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I need some help here guys, my issue is that the first `console.log` returns what has been built by the `foreach`, but the backend doesn't receive that same array. This `foreach` basically iterates over a table, looks for a certain id, makes it an index of an array, and then it fetches all the input values from the table and pushes it to that given index.

```
        var dateTime = [];
        $("#employeeData > tr").each(function(dateIndex, date) {
            dateTime[date.id] = [];
            $("#" + date.id + " :input").each(function(inputIndex, inputTime) {
                dateTime[date.id].push($(inputTime).val())
            });
        });
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        console.log(dateTime);
        $.post('employee',
            {
                dates: dateTime,
                _token: CSRF_TOKEN
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
        });
    Route::post('/employee', 'EmployeesController@updateRecords');

    public function updateRecords(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->dates;
    }
    // this is a console.log of the dateTime, each date has 4 inputs 
    //associated with it
    [2017-11-02: Array(4), 2017-11-03: Array(4), 2017-11-06: Array(4), 2017- 
    11-07: Array(4), 2017-11-08: Array(4), …]
```

This all happens when jquery handles a click event.

Comment: can u show ur controller code?

Comment: Can you paste your controller code (backend) and your routing page as well?

Comment: It's shared, along with the event mention.

Comment: the controller will recieve JSON data which you first need to `json_decode()` before you can `$request->dates`

Comment: As in return json_decode($request->dates);? didn't work. And if that were the case why does a dummy array work?

Comment: no as in: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to pass an array as it is in the post, it should be converted.

Just encode your array as JSON string and decode it in the backend.

```
var dateTime = [];
    $("#employeeData > tr").each(function(dateIndex, date) {
        dateTime[date.id] = [];
        $("#" + date.id + " :input").each(function(inputIndex, inputTime) {
            dateTime[date.id].push($(inputTime).val())
        });
    });
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    console.log(dateTime);
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dateTime);
    $.post('employee',
        {
            dates: jsonString,
            _token: CSRF_TOKEN
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
    });
```

in your PHP, decode the JSON string :

```
$dates = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['dates']));
```

Comment: Returns an empty array, the data after the console log isn't reaching the backend.

Comment: In your version, when i console.log the jsonString, it is empty, before the $.post.

Comment: So the json encoding did not work with stringify function

Comment: It won't make a difference, the jsonString is empty, i logged it to the console, this is impossible theoretically, because i built the array on a loop before it.

Comment: There is only one explanation, the post request happens before the array is built, so it is empty, but there is a loop that builds the array before it.

Comment: Can you please show a sample result of the first console.log(dateTime)

Comment: The array is in bad format. try this when filling the array: `dateTime[date.id+""].push($(inputTime).val()+"")`

Comment: It's the same, the data inside the array keys were already strings, what i posted was just the closed logged array.

Comment: Please note that the values in the array are also arrays (sub arrays), it seems that it should be changed to something giving the value needed. Also this link could help to resolve the empty result given by JSON.stringify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259728/json-stringify-returning

Comment: After a test, your note must be considered, because i created a dummy array with 2 dimensions that also does not reach the backend, what am i supposed to do then? It makes sense that the array has 2 dimensions and the keys are dynamic.

Comment: That is not actualy the issue, if i console.log the array with a hardcoded key of the first dimension, it gets shown up in the log and still doesn't reach the backend.

Comment: The JSON.stringify (function to encode array as JSON) handles this (it can encode a multidimensional array) and in the backend you could access every value after decoding. But what makes a real issue is the empty result returned by JSON.stringify, have you checked and tried the solutions in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259728/json-stringify-returning

Comment: Well, i had previosuly thought about turning it into an object, but i was not sure the objects worked in the same manner as arrays in terms of pushing stuff to it and creating keys, so i sort of hesitated. That is the final solution, thanks!